# Forecast Package from R in Python

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

I found forecast package from R the best solution for time series analysis and forecasting.

I want to use it in Python. Could I use rpy and after take the forecast package in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could use the [no longer developed or extended, but maintained] package RPy, or you could use the newer package RPy2 which is actively developed.

There are other options too, as eg headless network connections to Rserve.